# Oracle 19 - RMAN can't connect to database

Tags: oracle, configuration, rman, oracle-19c

I have troubles with starting RMAN and connecting to target database.

I start RMAN (`$ORACLE_HOME` & `$ORACLE_SID` env variables are set)

```
[oracle@MY_MACHINE /]$ /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/bin/rman
```

RMAN starts sucessfully...

```
Recovery Manager: Release 19.0.0.0.0
.
.
```

Then i try to execute this command to connect to the target database:

```
RMAN> Connect target /
```

But this fails with this error:

```
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
ORA-27140: attach to post/wait facility failed
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:invalid_egid failed with status: 1
ORA-27301: OS failure message: Operation not permitted
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: skgpwinit6
ORA-27303: additional information: startup egid = 54321 (oinstall), current egid = 54329 (asmadmin)
```

From my research I did, I found some resources that said the problem is usually wrong permissions on `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle` binary. They should be set to `chmod 6751`.

I verified that the permissions on the binaries are correct and they seem to be.

```
[oracle@MY_MACHINE /]$ ls -lah /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/bin/oracle
-rwsr-s--x. 1 oracle asmadmin 421M Dec 23  2020 /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/bin/oracle
```

Do you have any other ideas what might be causing this error?

Thank you

### Additional details

- Oracle Linux Server 7.9
- GRID + ASM installed
- Two Oracle homes:

```
[oracle@MY_MACHINE /]$ ls  /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/
dbhome_1  grid
```

- Groups of the `oracle` user:

```
[oracle@MY_MACHINE /]$ groups
oinstall dba oper backupdba asmdba asmoper asmadmin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this error:

current egid = 54329 (asmadmin)

before running RMAN command the primary group was asmadmin.
So, just adjust current user permissions before running RMAN with the command:

**newgrp oinstall**

Comment: You we're right. It has been caused by running wrong newgrp commands before executing RMAN.